# Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError while uploading file to digitalocean space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, certificate

I’m following the [How To Use ActiveStorage in Rails 6 with DigitalOcean Spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-activestorage-in-rails-6-with-digitalocean-spaces) tutorial and after setting up DigitalOcean Space and trying to upload an image I get the following error

```
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unspecified certificate verification error))
```

I’m running the app with ruby 2.7.1 on macOS 13.0 on M1 chip. ruby has been compiled with the following options

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in incorrect bucket name in the storage config. bucket should be the same as the endpoint jsut without `https://` part

```
digitalocean:
  endpoint: https://bucket-name.region.digitaloceanspaces.com
  bucket: bucket-name.region.digitaloceanspaces.com
```